# Need a non-technical end user Google Analytics guide, suggestions?

Tags: google-analytics, guide

What I'm looking for: Super simply, basic intro to using Google Analytics target to non-technical end users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the Google Conversion University playlist on youtube. It has a wide range of videos with an intro to Google Analytics and info on using the data to make good decisions. 
http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=7A545E796C2CFA72

You may also want to check out http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/

Comment: +1 Thanks, though I'm not really looking analytic management how to guides. Really looking for a super simple guide: login, view default reports, logout; possible I'm making it to simple though. Not even really expecting the client to even use it, but it's easy to setup and feature rich.

Comment: Those resources are SUPER though, guess I'll just have to use them for me... :-)

Comment: On the Google Analytics site they have a product tour http://www.google.com/analytics/tour.html this is a pretty simple overview. In my experience most non technical/non web people won't use their analytics account unless you can show them actionable items based on the data, if you're doing this for clients you'll probably be better off discussing their goals then build a report specifically for them and schedule it to be emailed once a week or month, that way they only get the data they are interested in and they don't have to do anything to get it.